# FolderSync alternative for Windows

Tags: windows, sync

I use [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) on my Android devices to sync my files & folders across cloud & devices. It can pair local & remote folders for two-way sync as well as one-way sync (up & down). It supports filters to include/exclude file types. It supports following services:

- Amazon S3
- Dropbox
- Box.net (WebDAVs)
- SugarSync
- Google Docs
- Skydrive
- NetDocuments
- LiveDrive (WebDAV/FTP)
- HiDrive (WebDAV/FTP)
- FTP, FTPS, FTPES
- SFTP (SSH File Transfer)
- Samba/CIFS/Windows Share
- Ubuntu One
- WebDAV
- WebDAVs (HTTPS)

I am looking for an Windows alternative which could do same things.

Answer (score 3):

[GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/) supports most of those services, and should match your other requirements as well.

Comment: I have already checked it... no Dropbox support.. :(